# SCCM 2012 R2 OSD pxe-32 : tftp open timeout

Tags: cisco, pxe-boot, dhcp-server, wds, sccm-2012

I have SCCM 2012 R2 standalone primary site on windows server 2012 and i have Cisco dhcp server i configured the distribution point for pxe boot to work with osd i added boot images and configured them and the network guy configured the next server option to point to sccm server on the dhcp and the pxe boot fails we tried option 66 it fails also then we tried option 67 and it fails again we always get the same error message  pxe-32 : tftp open timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all i solved the issue actually two weeks ago by configuring only the 
1- next server option   the sccm fqdn or the IP
2- the boot file option smsboot\x86\pxeboot.com

and allow the traffic between the sccm server and the client machines throw fortigate firewall

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using option 66 and 67 together? What did you fill in in option 67? Have you filled in this in option 67 SMSBoot\x64\wdsnbp.com
In option 66 should be the IP of the SCCM server

Comment: yes the two options together and the 67 SMSBoot\x86\wdsnbp.com, and the 66 the ip of the sccm server

Comment: Do you receive an IP? At PXE boot

Comment: some other points:

* Are the boot images distributed?
* Do they have network drivers?

Comment: yes the client receives ip from dhcp and the boot images distributed but i didn't inject the boot images with network driver

Comment: So, did it work? After injecting the drivers? I would recommend just injecting universal Intel (if it is intel based) network drivers. 

Make sure you clear the PXE deployments of that group in assets before you deploy again.

Comment: no it didn't work i can't see why its not working i made a boot media and everything worked correctly but over the network its not working

Comment: Did you create your own boot images of that of sccm? Try adding the boot images again and changing the properties as you like and than distributing them again. I have had this before and solved it like this. This is a good way to do it http://www.niallbrady.com/2013/10/09/how-can-i-manually-add-winpe-5-boot-images-to-system-center-2012-configuration-manager-sp1-cu3/

Comment: i configured port to be with the sccm server on the same subnet and it worked now i know its the cisco dhcp issue,

Comment: Any suggestion on modifying the cisco dhcp configuration

Answer (score 0):

In my case, WDS Service was stopped after an upgrade.
Just check if all required services are started after an upgrade